# SQL - Convert number to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a number to a decimal with two decimals places.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),12345)
```

The above would return 12345.00 but I'm trying to achieve 123.45

Comment: How about `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),12345/100.00)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need something like that:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),12345/100.0)
```

Comment: Sorry, my first comment omitted the decimal; it should have been: `SELECT 12345/100.0` gives you a numerically equivalent result. Dividing an `int` by a `decimal` returns a `decimal`, so in the end all the convert is doing is specifying the length and precision.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),CAST(12345 as float)/CAST(100 as float))
```

Answer (score -3):

**Correction**: The premise is somewhat flawed, as the data type of a literal number without a decimal point is `int`, not `numeric` as implied by the question. In that case, you do need to convert the initial value to either `numeric` or `decimal` before dividing:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL,12345)/100
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(12345 AS DECIMAL)/100
```

(`cast` is the SQL standard, so if you ever want to apply this to other databases, it would be the preferred method.)

Alternately, you can just add a decimal point to the divisor, as SQL server will return the more precise data type when doing arithmetic on heterogeneous types:

```
SELECT 12345/100.0
```

---

[According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), the `numeric` data type is functionally equivalent to the `decimal` datatype, so there's really no reason to convert between the two. It seems that all you really want to do is divide the value you have by 100:

```
SELECT 12345/100
```

Comment: Did you even try that?

Comment: It gives you 123 so no, he didn't try it.

Comment: Numeric may be equivalent to decimal, but 12345 is not numeric it's int.